# Is there a solution to solve this mysterious time encoding?

Tags: date, time, binary, hex, decoding

I'm currently trying to understand the encoding of my cable receiver (it's a xoro XORO HRM 7670) and I'm not getting it at all.
I tried to find any kind of documentation for the device, the os behind it or even the chip - without any success. I'm just trying to decode the folloing date pattern in the record meta data:
(there is no date information stored in the file attributes)

Here is what I got:

```
88 28 C5 00 00 00 00 00 19 00 00 00 F8 D5 4F 4E 45 20 48 44 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 07 F7 80 E4 27  
1A [01 11 03] 01 00 0F 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF 
FF B9 06 0C 00 00 00 B9 06 02 00 00 00 BA 06 03 00 00 00 67 65
72 BB 06 03 00 00 00 6D 69 73 01 00 00 00 BC 06 01 01 00 64 65
75 01 00 00 00 B8 06 01 00 01 00 64 65 75 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 27 27 01 F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I identified the 3 pairs in the brackets as time by diffing with a other record.
Chaning this values produces following output from the receiver:

```
HEX      -> TIME SHOWN
00:00:01 -> 00:00:02
00:00:02 -> 00:00:04
03:03:03 -> 12:03:06
01:01:01 -> 04:01:02
11:11:11 -> 04:17:34
FF:FF:FF -> 60:127:127
```

But I'm not getting it...

Edit: further observations after comment:

```
F5 94 91 -> 23:20:35
0F 00 00 -> 63:00:00
00 40 00 -> 03:64:00
00 B0 00 -> 03:48:01
```

Seen for the hours:
00 produces 0, okay
11 produces 4 -> why?
03 -> produces 12???

Could be, that there is some relation between the pairs (like seconds or sth.).
Btw. I'm quite sure, the 3 pairs before the marked are used as date - should be the 26.04.2020.

Can anybody solve this binary riddle with me?
Thanks,
Jonas

Comment: All your examples have got the first two bytes equal, so it’s hard to deduce the role of each. Try for example `0F 00 00`, `00 40 00` and `00 B0 00`. Also try hard if you can find a way to generate an hour that isn’t divisible by 4. One would expect that it should be possible some way.

Comment: Okay, here is what i got
F5 94 91 -> 23:20:35
0F 00 00 -> 63:00:00
00 40 00 -> 03:64:00
00 B0 00 -> 03:48:01

Comment: Wow, all of those examples have added 3 to the hours compared to what I said in my answer. And I cannot explain exactly why, sorry. Also you’ve managed to get an odd number of seconds, that’s interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a complete answer, but some tentative observations:

- It seems that the last four bits of the first byte (the second hex char) are concatenated with two 0 bits to produce the hour: 0 -> 0, 1 -> 100 binary = 4, 3 -> 1100 = 12, F -> 111100 = 60. The mystery to me is how to produce an hour that isn’t divisible by 4.
- The middle byte denotes the minutes, but limited to 127, the greatest possible value of a signed byte in 2-complement (values go from -128 through +127).
- One 0 bit is put after the last byte to get the seconds. Again they are limited to 127. For example 11 hex = 10001 binary -> 100010 = 34. Could it be that we haven’t got precision/granularity beyond 2 seconds?

Edit: I think you’ve got the best chances if at this point you study the effect of just one bit at a time. So try for example:

```
80 00 00
40 00 00
20 00 00
10 00 00
08 00 00
04 00 00
02 00 00
...
00 00 04
00 00 02 -> 00:00:04 // already known from your question
00 00 01 -> 00:00:02
```

They will be 24 tests in all. After those you will probably have a better idea which combinations you want to try next.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there are only even numbers as seconds available

Comment: Please see the comment above about the devisible by 3
Looks like the thrid char also got some connection to the hour
I've just got no clue, why somebody would implement that kind of strange time calculation in a not by size limited file ^^
Could there be any kind of specification to this sort of time representation?

Comment: Your new observations are interesting and frankly confused me. I have edited and suggest a path to follow from here. @JonasBorn